# How to fix focus/clickability of XUL textboxes?

Tags: textbox, focus, xul

On a normal webpage `<input type='text'/>`, in Firefox, you can click anywhere on the element and the browser will "focus" on that element.  On a XUL (Firefox extension) `<textbox>` element however, only clicking on the <strike>leftmost part</strike> edges of the textbox will focus it; clicking anywhere else on it does nothing.

I find this really annoying, especially given how input elements in Firefox work normally; I'd have better UI with a web page than with a browser extension!  Does anyone know of a way to fix this behavior (I was thinking maybe I could do an onClick="function(){this.focus()}" kinad thing, but that seems so hacky so I was really hoping there was a better way ...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So ... this ones a little embarrassing, but I thought I should share how I finally solved the problem properly.  As it turns out, XUL elements DO normally get focused on when click.  The problem, as I discovered, was that if you put those elements *inside* of another element that they aren't supposed to be inside of, *then* they stop being focused properly.  In my case I had ****sigh**** the following:

```
<groupbox align="start">
    <caption label="Test"/>
        <radiogroup>
```

wrapping all of the actual contents of my document (and I didn't even close them either; it was just a terrible un-noticed copy/paste error).

So, if you find yourself thinking you need the code in my first answer, check your XUL files first: the problem is probably your own code.

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured out a workaround, although I remain surprised that there isn't a less hacky way of solving this.  If anyone has a "real" fix, I'll happily award the answer to them.

```
<textbox id="foo" onclick="focusFunction('foo')"/>

function focusFunction(id) {
  document.getElementById(id).focus("")
}
```